# Create a new page to display site-wide total statistics

Tags: feature-request, reputation

It's cool that you can see the site-wide badge award counts on the badges page. How about adding something that shows site-wide rep stats, like total reputation accrued by all users — maybe a graph of that over time — or total numbers of upvotes/downvotes cast, bounty rep paid/awarded, &c.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you are not asking for a page that would show *your* stats across the different sites, but instead you are asking for stats on the entire userbase of SO in one place.  This would be a complement to the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page, which shows how many of which type of badge have been awarded to users on the site.  Your page would show:

- the total number of all reputation gained by all users,
- the total amount of votes cast, up and down across all the questions on Stack Overflow,
- the totals for bounties offered and received.
- potentially a graph of this data over time.

Though this might be an interesting feature on the site, I dont think it will rank high on the list.  Dont let that get you down, though.  You will be pleased to know that you have the ability to query for these stats already.  There are two sites out there that offer access to the free data dump without the need to import it into a database for querying on your own:

1. [statoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/data-dump-sandbox)
2. [stackql](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22869/stackql-yet-another-data-dump-sandbox)

as far as graphs are concerned, you might just want to sit on this site and watch for periodic updates from the likes of [Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs) and [Stu Thompson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/comment-analysis-from-latest-data-dump) among others.

Comment: while the badges page probably likes compliments, I think you mean complement

Comment: haha. right you are!