# Data dump and comments statistics

Tags: discussion, comments, data-dump

Did someone make an attempt at mining comments on the data dump?

I like comments very much, even though they are "second class citizens". I think they add a lot of spice to the trilogy sites.

I would like to know if someone has used the data dumps to produce interesting data regarding comments such as:

- The most commented questions
- The most commented answers
- The most voted comment
- The most prolific commenter
- The user whose posts are most commented
- Tags with highest relative number of comments

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com):

- [The most commented questions/answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104078/most-commented-posts)
- [Most voted comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104080/highest-voted-comments)
- [Most prolific commenters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104082/most-prolific-commenters)
- [Users whose posts are the most commented](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104084/users-whose-posts-are-most-commented)

You can carry on from there.

Comment: I'd done all the others before, but +1 for the last (4th) link. Hope you don't mind I updated your link there for one with line breaks and better column names (so you get links to user profiles). Also, Users by Comments Per Post: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104086/users-by-comments-per-post

Comment: Thanks for that, I was wondering why sometimes things created links and sometimes they didn't.

Comment: Also: Users by Comments Per Post for users with at least 10 posts: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104087/users-by-comments-per-post-min-10-posts (hurray for correctly using a HAVING clause on the first try :)

Answer (score 2):

[Stu Thompson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2961/stu-thompson) has posted [Comment Analysis from the Latest Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/comment-analysis-from-latest-data-dump) (from the Sept data dump).  It looks at the Number of Comments vs Average Score by User.